# Tracking down a 'GC overhead limit exceeded' error

Tags: java, garbage-collection, profiling

What is the easiest way to track down (i.e., find the cause of) a 'GC overhead limit exceeded' error?

What I do not consider good options:

- Adding the `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit` parameter to the JVM call. That Java exception is telling me there is something incredibly inefficient in my implementation, and I want to fix that.
- "Go and look carefully at your code". The project is very large, so I need some clues regarding *where* to look for inefficiencies.

Shoud I use a profiler? If yes, which one would you suggest?

Should I look into the GC log? I have tried doing that, but I have a little understanding of it, and it seems there are no clear pointers to the code (saying *which* objects are being GC'ed).

Many questions have been asked on SO about this error, but no one seems to answer this specific question.

Comment: Get a memory dump and analyze it using [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). Note: the product is from Eclipse, doesn't mean you need to use/have Eclipse in order to use this product.

Comment: A profiler is your best hope.  Start with VisualVM as it comes with  the JVM.  I use a commercial profiler called YourKit.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest tools to start profiling your app

Netbeans comes with a built in profiler.
Jconsole can also help a bit
VisualVm can also aid a bit.

Commercial Tools that is really awesome is DyanTrace

**Now for the approach to fix your problem:**
Although there can be other ways you can tackle it. but following things may help.
1) The symptoms that you are seeing are probably result of creation of too many short lived objects in your code. Now this is not a memory leak situation but too much garbage to clean for the JVM. And Jvm is failing to keep up with that. You need to check your code for where are these objects getting created.

2) Second thing you can do is take several heap dumps at regular intervals between two GC runs and  compare these heapdumps in netbeans or some other tool of your choice. you need to do this before your app goes into this bad state.This comparison will tell you what has grown in heap and may be will give you a pointer where to look into your code.

I hope this helps in solving your issue. :)

Comment: Did you try some the suggestions?

Comment: Not yet, when I find time to try it out, I'll let you know whether this was useful.